# Image Is Not Responsive in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at following code and let me know why the image is not acting responsive in Bootstrap 3?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!--My Style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="rainbow">
<img src="img/header.png" alt="DayCare" />
</div>
</div>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I test it on Bootstrap 2.3 and it was working fine ,Thanks

Comment: You say that the solution by Skelly doesn't work, could you create a JSFiddle with your problem? Fork this one here with Bootstrap included: http://jsfiddle.net/SjfzQ/

Answer (score 7):

Add 'img-responsive` class to the img...

```
<img src="img/header.png" class="img-responsive" alt="DayCare" />
```

Comment: Hi Skelly, I updated the code by adding the class="img-responsive" but the image still not acting responsive! Do I have to link to any responsive.css file like what we did on bootstrap 2.3 ?

Comment: @MonaCoder, you don't need any additional files for BS3.  However, your rainbow class might be messing things up if it's a fixed width, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily using like this:

```
<img src="img/header.png" style="width:100%; height:auto; display:block;" />
```

If width of the header image is smaller than the width of the screen, you should add the max-width in the style to keep the original width of the header in large views. For example, assuming the original width of the header is 600px, img should be like this:

```
<img src="img/header.png" style="width:100%; height:auto; display:block; max-width:600px" />
```

Comment: after this ,when reducing the display size, the image image act as responsive.But after re-size the window(display size) image still in that reduced display place. So I delete the `display:block;` from style and its work perfectly.Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Skelly, img-responsive works well.

I tried with this code (Style.css removed), works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="rainbow">
<img class="img-responsive" src="bootstrap/resources/img/charpente/toulenne/IMGP0110.JPG" alt="DayCare" />
</div>
</div>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try removing your Style.css